# Choosing the right LED IR and the photodiode for optical beam sensor

Tags: photodiode, detection, light-sensor, photosensor, optical

I need to design an optical beam sensor for about 15-20 cm of distance - any obstacle between an emitter and a detector would trigger an interrupt for a microcontroller.
I was thinking about using a single 940 nm LED and a photodiode, adding a simple comparator circuit. Is it a good solution? Which electrical/optical parameters are crucial when it comes to choosing the best suited components?

Comment: How will you collimate the IR beam?

Comment: (1) Can you eliminate ambient IR light? (2) A turtle breaking the beam compared with a bullet breaking the beam influences acceptable components...can you tighten-up your "any obstacle" spec?

Comment: If you don't plan on building a transimpedance amplifier for the photodiode, you are better off with a phototransistor. In any case, most of this is cheap enough and easy enough to breadboard to see if the parts you have chosen work at your distance and produce a comparator signal so you can do some trial and error in component selection.

Comment: @glen_geek (1) Well the whole thing will be operating in darkness, I'm not expecting any ambient light. Besides there's always possibility to use some modulation pattern. (2) Let's assume that this sensor should detect a moving ball with about 3 cm diameter. The ball is moving at a rate of max. a couple of meters per sec.

Comment: @Andyaka I wasn't aware that I should collimate the beam. Are there any collimators available for standard 3 and 5 mm LEDs?

Comment: Any reason you want to build this instead of buying an off the shelf IR sensor that would integrate everything you need? Haven't replaced the one on my garage door but I think it's pretty cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensing at 15-20 cm. for blocked-gate sensing requires a remote LED and photo-sensor. It is better to keep the photo-detector closest to microcontroller. The LED light source can accept DC current through two longer wires more easily.

For sensing a rolling-ball speed, as @DKNguyen has suggested - a **phototransistor** is an appropriate sensor. Its advantage is internal gain, whereas a **photodiode** has none. The *very fast* response-time of a photodiode isn't needed while a photo-resistor *might* be too slow-responding.

Consider using a RED LED rather than infra-red LED. Optical setup is so much easier when you can see the light source. Most phototransistors with transparent lens are perhaps twice as sensitive to IR LEDs compared with RED LEDs: the RED-LED penalty is not that bad, and you can always substitute-in an IR LED once troubleshooting with RED-LED is finished.
If you choose a phototransistor encased in resin that blocks visible light (often appears black-resin), then a IR-LED or incandescent lamp is your only option for a light source - a RED-LED will produce no output signal from such a phototransistor.

Choosing a LED encased in resin that collimates light into a narrow beam is important at such distances. Same for phototransistor. Shown below are two 3mm diameter phototransistors.

- The lens on the left device collects light from almost the full 3mm, and concentrates it onto the much-smaller internal phototransistor.
- The flat surface on the rightmost device collects light from 3mm as well, but doesn't concentrate it: the small internal phototransistor collects much less light.
  [image: two phototransistors, left:lens, right:flat(no lens)]

The **angles** where sensitivity drops to half are often used as a collimating figure-of-merit. A small angle is desired. The phototransistor above at left has a lens collection angle spanning about 16 degrees, while the right lens has collection angle of 120 degrees.

[image: RED LED 6 degree lens]

The 5mm diameter RED LED shown above radiates light over a 6 degree angle. Such a light source would throw more light into a small phototransistor at 20 cm distance than a LED with no built-in lens...this one claims a luminous intensity of 2500 millicandela when 20mA current is applied. Although you can find blue or green LEDs that appear to your eye *brighter*, a phototransistor or photodiode prefers red or infra-red light.

> a single 940 nm LED and a photodiode, adding a simple comparator circuit. Is it a good solution?

A photodiode sensor feeding a current-sense resistor would require a sensitive analog comparator to generate a digital signal. A photo transistor (with its internal gain) feeding a current-sense resistor *might* be sensitive enough to drive a microcontroller GPIO directly, especially in a dark environment that allows a larger-value resistor.

A dark environment likely allows a simple DC current to activate the LED. If ambient light cannot be controlled, the added complication of a modulated source might be required. Demodulation also required at photo-detector.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer and sharing the knowledge. I will definitely consider using a phototransistor.